# horizontal center of floated images

Tags: html, css, css-float

how can I straighten out images with different width.
They are all floated right. I want to have them right beneath.

The example window is small for best displaying so try it in fullscreen on your computer.

```css
.kompresor{
 height: 150px;
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>

<a href="../fotky/ESM250.gif" rel=lightbox[kompresor1] data-title="kompresor Gardner Denver ESM250"><img src="http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/ESM250.gif" title="kompresor Gardner Denver ESM250" alt="kompresor Gardner Denver ESM250" class="kompresor"></a>
- Mazné šroubové kompresory systém zatíženo – odlehčeno, typ <b>ESM 2 -500</b>
<ul>
<li>Stálá rychlost motoru</li>
<li>Dodávaný objem: 0,24 – 73,60 m<sup>3</sup> /min</li>
<li>Výstupní tlak: 5 - 13 bar</li>
<li>Výkon až 500kW</li>
</ul>
</div>


<div>
- Mazné šroubové kompresory s frekvenčním měničem, typ <b>VS7 – VS290</b>
<a href="../fotky/GD_VS7.gif" rel=lightbox[kompresor2] data-title="kompresor Gardner Denver VS7"><img src="http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/GD_VS7.gif" title="kompresor Gardner Denver VS7" alt="kompresor Gardner Denver VS7" class="kompresor"></a>
<ul>
<li>Proměná rychlost motoru = vyšší efektivita provozu</li>
<li>Dodávaný objem: 0,41 – 42,30 m<sup>3</sup> /min</li>
<li>Výstupní tlak: 5 - 13 bar</li>
<li>Výkon až 290kW</li>
</ul>
</div>


<div>
- Bezmazné šroubové kompresory řady <b>Ultima U75 – 160 PureAir</b>
<a href="../fotky/Ultima U75-160_PureAir.gif" rel=lightbox[kompresor3] data-title="kompresor Gardner Denver Ultima U75-U160"><img src="http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/Ultima U75-160_PureAir.gif" title="kompresor Gardner Denver Ultima U75-U160" alt="kompresor Gardner Denver Ultima U75-U160" class="kompresor"></a>
<ul>
<li>Jedinečný design – vysoká efektivita, nízký hluk</li>
<li>Proměná rychlost motoru</li>
<li>100% čistý vzduch bez oleje, splňuje ISO 8573-1 Class Zero (2010)</li>
<li>Výkon až 160kW</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the images to form a column to the right of the text and to be centered, you can try the following HTML mark-up and CSS.

(1) Add a wrapper block level element `div.table-wrap` and set `display: table`.

(2) Set `display: table-row` for the child `div` elements.

(3) Re-position the top (title) line of text as the first `li` of the `ul` block and give it the class `title` and style as desired.  Position the `a` element to follow the `ul` block.

(4) Apply `display: table-cell` to the `ul` and `a` elements, note the use `vertical-align: top` and `text-align: center` on the `a` element.

(5) Adjust margins and padding to get a balance in the whitespace.

The use of the wrapper with `display: table` will allow you to center the images in a CSS-table column.  If desired, you can center the table.

The layout is reasonably responsive and gives you some control over white space using margins and padding.

```css
div.table-wrap {
  display: table;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto; /* Optional: if you want to center the table/panels */
}

div.table-wrap div {
  display: table-row;
}

div.table-wrap ul {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div.table-wrap ul li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

div.table-wrap ul li.title {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.00em;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

div.table-wrap a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}

div.table-wrap a img {
  height: 175px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

div.table-wrap ul, div.table-wrap a {
  padding-bottom: 10px; /* Controls the spacing between rows/panels */
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrap">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="title">- Mazné šroubové kompresory systém zatíženo – odlehčeno, typ <b>ESM 2 -500</b></li>
      <li>Stálá rychlost motoru</li>
      <li>Dodávaný objem: 0,24 – 73,60 m<sup>3</sup> /min</li>
      <li>Výstupní tlak: 5 - 13 bar</li>
      <li>Výkon až 500kW</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="../fotky/ESM250.gif" rel=lightbox[kompresor1] data-title="kompresor Gardner Denver ESM250"><img src="http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/ESM250.gif" title="kompresor Gardner Denver ESM250" alt="kompresor Gardner Denver ESM250" class="kompresor"></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="title">- Mazné šroubové kompresory s frekvenčním měničem, typ <b>VS7 – VS290</b></li>
      <li>Proměná rychlost motoru = vyšší efektivita provozu</li>
      <li>Dodávaný objem: 0,41 – 42,30 m<sup>3</sup> /min</li>
      <li>Výstupní tlak: 5 - 13 bar</li>
      <li>Výkon až 290kW</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="../fotky/GD_VS7.gif" rel=lightbox[kompresor2] data-title="kompresor Gardner Denver VS7"><img src="http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/GD_VS7.gif" title="kompresor Gardner Denver VS7" alt="kompresor Gardner Denver VS7" class="kompresor"></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li class="title">- Bezmazné šroubové kompresory řady <b>Ultima U75 – 160 PureAir</b></b>
      </li>
      <li>Jedinečný design – vysoká efektivita, nízký hluk</li>
      <li>Proměná rychlost motoru</li>
      <li>100% čistý vzduch bez oleje, splňuje ISO 8573-1 Class Zero (2010)</li>
      <li>Výkon až 160kW</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="../fotky/Ultima U75-160_PureAir.gif" rel=lightbox[kompresor3] data-title="kompresor Gardner Denver Ultima U75-U160"><img src="http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/Ultima U75-160_PureAir.gif" title="kompresor Gardner Denver Ultima U75-U160" alt="kompresor Gardner Denver Ultima U75-U160" class="kompresor"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, I made a mistake in describing my problem. I want them to be centered but still have them on right side. For eg.: image with 200px width, image with 150px width and image with 100px width. Image with 150px will have 'margin-right: (200-150)/2 = 25', image with 100px width will have 'margin-right: (200-100)/2 = 50px'. I am not sure if I made this example right but I meant that all img have same center point.

Comment: If I can alter the markup, then I can propose a solution (a bit later when I get back to the desk).

Answer (score 2):

When you use `float`, the floating object does not contribute to the parent object's height. The next `<div>` is not able to use the full width, because it is not fully below the floating image from the previous `<div>`. You need to use `clear: both;` to get it to start fully below all floating objects. I have edited your example code to show this:

```css
.kompresor{
 height: 150px;
 float: right;
}
.clear-both {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div>

<a href="../fotky/ESM250.gif" rel=lightbox[kompresor1] data-title="kompresor Gardner Denver ESM250"><img src="http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/ESM250.gif" title="kompresor Gardner Denver ESM250" alt="kompresor Gardner Denver ESM250" class="kompresor"></a>
- Mazné šroubové kompresory systém zatíženo – odlehčeno, typ <b>ESM 2 -500</b>
<ul>
<li>Stálá rychlost motoru</li>
<li>Dodávaný objem: 0,24 – 73,60 m<sup>3</sup> /min</li>
<li>Výstupní tlak: 5 - 13 bar</li>
<li>Výkon až 500kW</li>
</ul>
</div>


<div class="clear-both">
- Mazné šroubové kompresory s frekvenčním měničem, typ <b>VS7 – VS290</b>
<a href="../fotky/GD_VS7.gif" rel=lightbox[kompresor2] data-title="kompresor Gardner Denver VS7"><img src="http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/GD_VS7.gif" title="kompresor Gardner Denver VS7" alt="kompresor Gardner Denver VS7" class="kompresor"></a>
<ul>
<li>Proměná rychlost motoru = vyšší efektivita provozu</li>
<li>Dodávaný objem: 0,41 – 42,30 m<sup>3</sup> /min</li>
<li>Výstupní tlak: 5 - 13 bar</li>
<li>Výkon až 290kW</li>
</ul>
</div>


<div class="clear-both">
- Bezmazné šroubové kompresory řady <b>Ultima U75 – 160 PureAir</b>
<a href="../fotky/Ultima U75-160_PureAir.gif" rel=lightbox[kompresor3] data-title="kompresor Gardner Denver Ultima U75-U160"><img src="http://matmasar.wz.cz/fotky/Ultima U75-160_PureAir.gif" title="kompresor Gardner Denver Ultima U75-U160" alt="kompresor Gardner Denver Ultima U75-U160" class="kompresor"></a>
<ul>
<li>Jedinečný design – vysoká efektivita, nízký hluk</li>
<li>Proměná rychlost motoru</li>
<li>100% čistý vzduch bez oleje, splňuje ISO 8573-1 Class Zero (2010)</li>
<li>Výkon až 160kW</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry, I didn´t express myself well. I want them to be centered but still have them on right side. For eg.: image with 200px width, image with 150px width and image with 100px width. Image with 150px will have 'margin-right: (200-150)/2 = 25', image with 100px width will have 'margin-right: (200-100)/2 = 50px'. I am not sure if I made this example right but I meant that all img have same center point.